# Toastr not working in conjuction with AngularJs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, toastr

I am trying to use `Toastr` with `angular js`, but getting the following error. I have included `jquery.js` file as expected.

```
src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"
```

Error message:

> angular.js:11594 TypeError: Cannot read property 'extend' of undefined
>
> at m (toastr.js:474)
>   at Object.o [as info] (toastr.js:474)
>   at ProductTableController.showAddToCartToast (productTable.directive.js:207)
>   at ProductTableController.addToCart (productTable.directive.js:159)
>   at angular.js:12332
>   at f (angular.js:22949)
>       at a.$$ChildScope.$$ChildScope.$eval (angular.js:14383)
>       at a.$$ChildScope.$$ChildScope.$apply (angular.js:14482)
>       at HTMLButtonElement. (angular.js:22954)
>       at HTMLButtonElement.dispatch (jquery.js:4670)(anonymous function) @ angular.js:11594(anonymous function) @ angular.js:8544$apply @ angular.js:14484(anonymous function) @ angular.js:22954dispatch @ jquery.js:4670r.handle @ jquery.js:4338

Any idea what's wrong ?

Thanks.

Comment: any error you getting in console  ?

Comment: No, just the one I added in the question.

Comment: demo http://codeseven.github.io/toastr/demo.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you included Jquery file after angular.js. Move your Jquery file above Angularjs file.

eg.

```
1. <script src ="jquery.min.js"></script>
2. <script src ="angular.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Close, toastr.js was above angular.js

Comment: oh.. I was knowing issue must be something like this.

Answer (score 0):

you can use [angular-toastr](https://github.com/Foxandxss/angular-toastr) library instead

install:  `bower install angular-toastr`

include dependency: `angular.module('app', ['ngAnimate', 'toastr'])`

use in controller :

```
app.controller('foo', function($scope, toastr) {
  toastr.success('Hello world!', 'Toastr fun!');
});
```